# Issues with load balancer finding the siteminder session cookie

Tags: liferay

When we are in loadbalancer then the proper login is not happening in liferay but when we are in individual server it works.

ANy idea we are using siteminder authentication

Answer (score 0):

I guess siteminder and load balancer are standing before the liferay servers in the network. And i guess your problem is you want the session to be sticky to the same liferay server so the load balancer has to see the siteminder session cookie after successful login to siteminder?

If this is the case (please be more specific) then it is not a problem of liferay, but only of siteminder und loadbalancer.

(I know liferay, but not siteminder and I cannot guess your load balancer)